# Twenty Seventeen Theme - scrolling text over background images

Tags: theme-twenty-seventeen

I’m using Twenty Seventeen with a static front page with 4 additional sections. On the very top part, as you scroll down, the logo, site name, and tagline scroll up over the opening image. There’s a clear background to the logo, title, tagline group, so the background image shows through.

As you scroll down further, the 2nd image comes into view, and it’s completely displayed when the 1st image has scrolled off the screen and the menu is now at the top. Continue scrolling and the text of the next section scrolls up, covering over the 2nd image. However, this text has a white (in my case) background and the image does NOT show through.

This is the same behavior for the remaining image/text pairs. What I want to know how to do is make the background on those text sections clear, like in the topmost section. I’ve seen how their color can be changed, but not how it can be made to be transparent.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The page I need help with: https://lonewolfleagues.com

Comment: while generally the 2017 theme is on topic, css related questions are not, and neither browser bugs, nor bugs in the theme itself. If you use the vanilla theme and observe a bug, you should report it on the wordpress trac.

Comment: This is the most complicated theme I've ever seen, it's not what I'd call ordinary CSS by any stretch. I thought someone familiar with Twenty Seventeen would be more likely able to help than just a CSS person. My bad. If I knew how to delete this question I would. I've opened up a similar one on ProWebmasters but the only response was to go look in Chrome dev-tools. Sheesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else needs this info.

This answer was provided by Andrew Nevins over on the Wordpress.org forums:

.site-content-contain { background-color: transparent; }

Simple once you find it.